# PSQL: Unable to enter password

Tags: postgresql, windows-10, psql

I have installed postgreSQL version 11.1 on my windows-x64 laptop and I'm able to access the database through pgAdmin 4.

However I can't access the database through command prompt. It ask's password but doesn't allows to enter. I have tried re-installing the software but it didn't work.Also, I have added bin & lib folder path to Enviorment variables. Please advise.

[image]

**Error message :** Password authentication failed for user abc

[image]

Comment: Is it giving you an error? If so, what?

Comment: Fatal: password authentication failed for user abc

Comment: How do you know it doesn't allow inputting the password? If based on nothing happening on screen while typing it's not supposed to print anything back when you type it in.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen It does accepts details for server, database, port & username but when it comes to password, it stops. I tried typing and copy paste but no luck

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can enter your password just fine. The password does not show up in the terminal when you type it, but that is for security reasons. **Just try typing your password out, and hitting enter.**

If your password was entered correctly, the action will continue. If your password was spelled wrong, it will prompt you to enter it again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

When you start your terminal, you're logged in as you (aka NOT postgres). So, when connecting to psql via terminal, you have to specify the user (in this case, postgres). So, from your terminal, you would type: `psql <database you want to connect to> <'postgres' or whatever postgres user you want to log in as>`. Then it'll prompt you for password: either hit enter if no password or type password. Then it should connect you to psql.

Other workaround of course is to start psql

Answer (score 1):

I've just installed PostgreSQL and had the same issue. Know that it simply hides your password so don't worry. Your keyboard doesn't block. Even if you don't see yourself typing, put your password and hit enter:
[Check this link to my cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNc5v.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are receiving a `Fatal: password authentication failed for user abc` error, this means that you are incorrectly inputing the password for that specified user.

If you do not know the password, you can fix this by logging into PSQL as a superuser and change the password for the `abc` account this way. You can do this with:

```
>>> psql -U postgres
postgres=# ALTER USER abc PASSWORD 'myPassword';
```

Comment: Windows doesn't have `sudo`

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: @shane  Thank you Shane. I just tried still unable to type password when I type first line and hit enter. Any more suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you click enter after the first line?

Comment: I have added the screenshot in question. I am able to login to pgAdmin 4 - Anything which I should do from this screen to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

default user for postgres is postgres and doesn't have password, so in pgadmin you can not access because you must enter password.

you must use psql client some command like this: psql -U postgres (I don't know in windows!) and just type \password to set your password

Answer (score 0):

[PasswordEnteredIMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G4m0.png)

It's just the inbuilt mechanism that hides the entered password. Just enter the correct password **even if it doesn't show your typing progress** and hit enter it will work, well it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just type your password and hit enter, PSQL hides the password

Answer (score 0):

i have this error 
i solve this by following method:
first i enter my password in pgadmin and later enter in psql

Comment: This answer doesn't really provide any additional information that hasn't already been given.

Answer (score 0):

What @Madao mentioned is correct:

"You can enter your password just fine. The password does not show up in the terminal when you type it, but that is for security reasons. Just try typing your password out, and hitting enter.

If your password was entered correctly, the action will continue. If your password was spelled wrong, it will prompt you to enter it again. It worked for me."

However this was NOT working for me when I run the SQL Shell (psql) normally from the Windows Start menu. I had to run the SQL Shell (psql) as an administrator and then the SQL Shell (psql) worked for me.

So, for anyone else who faces this issue, do the following:

1. Type in "psql" in the Windows Start menu.
2. When you see "SQL Shell (psql)" in the start menu, right click it and select
   "Open File Location".
3. Once in the file location, right click on the "SQL Shell (psql)" shortcut
   and then select "Run as Administrator".
4. Once you open "SQL Shell (psql)" as an administrator enter the requested
   information below (remember you wont see the password even though you're
   entering it):

```
Server [localhost]: localhost
Database [postgres]: Name_of_your_Database
Port [5432]: 5432
Username [postgres]: postgres
Password for user postgres: your_password
```

5. If you entered the above correctly you should see the below output in the
   shell:

```
psql (14.2)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

Your_Database_Name=#
```

Answer (score -3):

At first type,

```
psql -U postgres
```

After that just type the password that you have set in starting and press enter. Password is hidden just type the correct password. This works for me.